# Use NodeJS's 'googleapis' behind school proxy + npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, proxy, google-api-nodejs-client

In my school I am using a laptop to code while I don't have lesssons.

Unfortunately I can't use 'googleapis' or 'npm install' since I get 'etimedout' errors.

I already know the proxy IP and the port, since they are set in the internet settings from the computer, which I can access and edit trough a trick.

I already tried to disable the proxy, which results in no internet connection at all, as well as adding the IP from googleapis to the exceptions for the proxy.

In addition to that I tried to set the proxy IP and the port using 'npm config set proxy'. But I think I need a password for that.

Any ideas how I can bypass the proxy to make requests and use npm?

Thank you in advance